# javaweb response setAttribute can not get

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am a beginner. I want to practice on servlets.  In the same servlet I don't know why I cant get the attritube, after `forward` I also can't get the attribute.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    request.setAttribute("aa","asd");
    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("aa"));
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/classes/ResultServlet");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request,response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println() will print your output on console.
```

You need to use following for print on servlet.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(request.getAttribute("aa"));
```

In `getRequestDispatcher()` you need to provide url of resource. You have passed class file path of servlet. Files under `WEB-INF` are not directly accessible.
Put your servlet files under `src` folder with some package. And pass servlet name only.